# SharePoint list - "new experience" issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

We have a site migrated from SharePoint 2013 to SPO. I changed the list view to "new experience" and it worked fine. But now I logged with a different account and the list displays a "classic experience" even though "new" is selected in Advanced Settings. This is not the case of cache. It's not the matter of some special list features that cause the list to revert to "classic" either.
Basically, the list opens with "new experience" for one account and "classic" for other.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please clear browser cache, then have a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was and old content editor web part added to the list, which was a SP13 leftover. Deleting it fixed the issue. It had to be deleted, not just closed.

Comment: Congratulations on solving this issue and thanks for sharing your solution.

Please remember to accept your solution as answer.

It will do great help to those who meet the similar question in this forum.

Thanks again for your contribution.